# How to add namespace to xml file with linq

Tags: c#, xml

I am loading a xml file like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
```

this `test.xml` file has nodes like `<o:abc> <o:bcd>`
but o is not declared. I tried using this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\c0kohka\\Desktop\\test.xml");
XNamespace o = "http:\\abc.html" ;
```

Its not working gives error prefix o is undeclared. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your XML is invalid.

[Namespaces in an XML document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Namespace) must be declared **in the document** by writing `xmlns:o="http://...` on a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've defined your `XNamespace`, you need to **use it**:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\c0kohka\\Desktop\\test.xml");
XNamespace o = "http:\\abc.html" ;  // this seems odd - usually, this would be o = "http://abc.company.com" or something

XElement someElement = xDoc.Descendants(o + "SomeElement");
```

or something like that - without seeing the XML it's just guesswork at best....

Answer (score 0):

Well your .xml file is invalid. So you have to "fix" your .xml file rather than anything else.